# Question regarding characters and point open topology

Tags: general-topology, circles, topological-groups

I was wondering why the following claim is correct:

Let **G*** be the group of all continuous homomorphisms from the topological group **G** and the unit circle (call it **T**). Then **G*** is an intersection of a closed set in the point open topology of all functions from **G** to **T** and **C(G,T)** (set of all continuous functions from **G** to **T**).

**G*** is also called a character.
Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a (continuous) function $f$ from $G$ to $T$ is a homomorphism can be expressed as a "closed condition", as it were, in the pointwise (product) topology on $T^G$. Namely, write for a fixed pair of $g,h \in G$:

$$A(g,h) = \{f \in T^G \mid f(g)\cdot f(h) = f(gh)\} = ((m_T \circ (\pi_g \Delta \pi_h)) \Delta \pi_{gh})^{-1}[\Delta_T]\text{,}$$

where $m_T$ is the multiplication map from $T \times T$ to $T$ (which is continuous) and for any group element $t \in G$, $\pi_t: T^G \rightarrow T$ is the projection onto the element $t$ (sending $f \in T^G$ to $f(t)$), which are all continuous by definition of the pointwise topology. Also, $\Delta_T = \{(x,x): x \in T\}$ is the diagonal in $T$ which is closed (as $T$ is Hausdorff), and $\Delta$ denotes the diagonal product of maps from a common domain (which produces continuous functions from continuous functions).

To expand a bit on this: $\pi_{gh}: T^G \rightarrow T$ is a projection, as are $\pi_g : T^G \rightarrow T$ and $\pi_h: T^G \rightarrow T$. The latter two are combined into a diagonal map $\pi_g \Delta \pi_h: T^G \rightarrow T \times T$, defined by $(\pi_g \Delta \pi_h)(f) = (f(g), f(h))$ (which is continuous as $\pi_g, \pi_h$ both are; a standard fact for product spaces). The latter is composed with $m_T$ so $(m_T \circ (\pi_g \Delta \pi_h))(f) = f(g)\cdot f(h) \in T$, and this is continuous as composition of continuous maps. Now, this last map is again combined as a diagonal product with the first-mentioned projection $\pi_{gh}$, so this total map $(m_T \circ (\pi_g \Delta \pi_h))\Delta \pi_{gh}$ sends $f$ to the pair $(f(g)\cdot f(h),f(gh))$. Which lies in $\Delta_T \subset T \times T$ iff the left hand side term equals the right hand side term.

So all sets $A(g,h)$ are closed and the homomorphisms in $T^G$ is just the set $\cap_{g,h \in G} A(g,h)$, which is also closed (in the pointwise topology) as the intersection of closed sets.

Comment: Looks good... I need to digest it for a little while. Will let you know if I came across any things that I may didn't understand completely. Thanks again :)

Comment: there is something that I don't quite understand. How can I take multiplication Map of diagonal product of maps? Multiplication map expects T×T while it receives a diagonal product of elements in T^G. Can you please extend the explanation of the RHS?

Comment: @AvivEshed I explained it fully. It's a pretty standard way to see that the set where equality holds is a closed set. One could use nets as well, but many people are not familiar with those.

Comment: Yes now it is clearer for me. Thank you :)

Comment: By the way, you saw the type of questions I have, is there a book you could recommend me that deals with the types of questions I asked?

Comment: @AvivEshed Topological Function Spaces (Arhangel'skij), about (mainly) the pointwise topology or more elementary: McCoy Ntantu: Topological Properties of Spaces of Continuous Functions, parts of Engelking (general topology).